# Se duplican los titulos al consumir una api

Tags: reactjs, api, table, material-ui

Estoy empezando con React y quiero consumir la API de pokemon, recibo ya los datos y los paso por una funcion map, luego por props le envio los datos a un componente donde tengo una tabla, la tabla esta hecha con Material-UI, el problema es que cuando quiero renderizar los datos dentro de la tabla los titulos se repiten 10 veces, como podria solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano!!

**Llamado a la API**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Lista } from '../components/Lista';

export const PokemonApi = () => {

    const [poke, setPoke] = useState([]);

    const data = () => {        
        
        axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=20').then(( response ) => {
    
            setPoke(response.data.results);
            console.log(response.data.results);
    
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    }

    useEffect(() => {

        data()

    }, []);

    return (

        <div>
            {
                poke.map(( info, id ) => {

                    return <Lista key={ id } info={ info } />

                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Tabla donde se debe renderizar**

```
export const Lista = (props) => {


    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            <Container maxWidth="md">
                <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                    <Table className={ classes.table } size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>Nombre</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">Img</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>

                        <TableBody>
                            <TableRow key={props.info.name}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {props.info.name}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{props.info.url}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>

                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Asi es como se ve la tabla:

[image: Titulos repetidos]

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo? Tengo el mismo problema y no logro dar con una solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está justamente en el map. Estás recorriendo todo el array de resultados y mostrando un componente Lista por cada elemento que exista en este.

Así pues, la línea de títulos aparecerá una vez por elemento. Para que funciona como quieres, lo único que debería estar dentro del bucle debería ser la siguiente parte:

```
<TableRow key={props.info.name}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {props.info.name}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{props.info.url}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
```

Comment: Osea que debo de moverlo a un componente unicamente con eso? Porque lo intente pero sigue ocurriendo el mismo inconveniente

Answer (score 0):

Esta sucediendo por el React Strict Mode, quita el componente <React.StrictMode> del archivo index.js y seguramente dejara de renderizarse varias veces.

debe quedar solo el App.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).